# Configure security permissions for site via code

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, permissions, 2016, claims-based-auth

In MOSS 2007, I used to use the following code to configure security permissions on a site (also created via code):

```
/*Line 1*/rootWeb.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups("CONTOSO\\SiteAdmin", "", "");
rootWeb.Update();

//----
// Add an admin domain security group to the Owners Group - FULL Access
//----
SPGroup SPOwnersGroup = site.RootWeb.AssociatedOwnerGroup;
/*Line 2*/SPUser ownerUsersByGroup = site.RootWeb.EnsureUser("CONTOSO\\SiteOwnersAccessGroup");
SPOwnersGroup.AddUser(ownerUsersByGroup);

// Add a contributor-level type domain security group the the Members Group - Contribute Access
SPGroup SPMembersGroup = site.RootWeb.AssociatedMemberGroup;
SPUser memberUsersByGroup = site.RootWeb.EnsureUser("CONTOSO\\SiteMembersAccessGroup");
SPMembersGroup.AddUser(memberUsersByGroup);
```

The above code is not working, and I think it has something to do with claims. If I change the `Line 1` to:

```
rootWeb.CreateDefaultAssociatedGroups("i:0#.w|CONTOSO\\SiteAdmin", "", "");
```

... the code moves on and fails at `Line 2`. `CONTOSO\SiteOwnersAccessGroup` is an AD security group. How do I go about adding specific users and AD security groups to the permissions groups of the site, without having to hard-code the claims format (which I am unfamiliar with)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First,** You can convert the loginname to calim using the below code

```
string userClaimsLoginName = "";
string userLoginNameWithDomain = @"mydomain\myuser";
string xmlTypeForString = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string";

// This will depend on your own implementation
string originalIssuer = SPOriginalIssuers.Format(SPOriginalIssuerType.Windows);

SPClaimProviderManager mgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
if (mgr != null)
{
    SPClaim claim = new SPClaim(SPClaimTypes.UserLogonName, userLoginNameWithDomain, xmlTypeForString, originalIssuer);
    userClaimsLoginName = mgr.EncodeClaim(claim);
}
```

**the output**

```
i:0#.w|mydomain\myuser
```

**Ref:** [Convert SharePoint login name to claims format and back using C#](https://ehikioya.com/convert-login-name-to-claims-format/)

---

**Second,** the below code would help you to add AD groupto your site

```
SPRoleDefinitionCollection roleDefinitions = newWeb.RoleDefinitions;
SPRoleAssignmentCollection roleAssignments = newWeb.RoleAssignments;
SPUser newUser = newWeb.EnsureUser("AD group");
newWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(newUser);
SPRoleDefinitionBindingCollection roleDefBindings = roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings;
roleDefBindings.Add(roleDefinitions["Read"]);
roleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
newWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
```